# Running total on a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

I am trying to add a running `count` to a `pandas df`.

For the values in `Column A`, I want to add `'5'` and for values in `Column B` I want to add  `'1'`.

So for the `df` below I'm hoping to produce:

```
   A  B Total
0  0  0     0
1  0  0     0
2  1  0     5
3  1  1     6
4  1  1     6
5  2  1    11
6  2  2    12
```

So for every incremental `integer` in `Column A`, it equal `'5'` in the total. While `Column B` is the `'+1'`.

I tried:

```
df['Total'] = df['A'].cumsum(axis = 0)
```

But this doesn't include Column B

Comment: I don't think that what you are trying to archive is called a cumulative sum

Comment: How you get `B` column? `df['B1'] = df['A'].cumsum()` return something else

Comment: @jezrael Column B is given. It is not dependent on column A

Comment: @Distjubo - I ask because not understand `While Column B is the standard '+1'.`

Comment: @jezrael I think the question needs to be lot more precisely formulated, but the way I read it is that the total value should be incremented by 1 if B is incremented by 1. But again, thats not a cumsum

Comment: @jezrael you're right. I haven't included Column B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `df['Total'] = df['A'] * 5 + df['B']`

As far as I can tell, you are simply doing row wise operations, not a cumulative sum. This snippet calculates the row value of `A` times 5 and adds the row value of `B` for each row. Please don't make it any more complicated than it really is.

### What is a cumulative sum (also called [running total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total))?

From Wikipedia:

> Consider the sequence <   5   8   3   2   >. What is the total of this sequence?
>
> **Answer**: 5 + 8 + 3 + 2 = 18. This is arrived at by simple summation of the sequence.
>
> Now we insert the number 6 at the end of the sequence to get <   5   8   3   2   6   >. What is the total of that sequence?
>
> **Answer**: 5 + 8 + 3 + 2 + 6 = 24. This is arrived at by simple summation of the sequence. But if we regarded 18 as the running total, we need only add 6 to 18 to get 24. So, 18 was, and 24 now is, the running total. In fact, we would not even need to know the sequence at all, but simply add 6 to 18 to get the new running total; as each new number is added, we get a new running total.

Comment: Thanks @Distjubo. Bit embarrassing. I've been using cumsum a bit lately. Needed to zoom out a bit more!